# Typings for a Mediator Pattern in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mediator

I'm trying to create a *typed* mediator pattern in TypeScript. The pattern itself is working without issues, but I would like to have it fully typed without redundancy (Not defining a specific type for the command registration and dispatcher separately).

This means that whenever I do:

```
dispatchCommand({
type: "SAVE_EVIDENCE_EVALUATION",
command: {
 // This gets autocompleted with the right typing
}
```

Here's what I've managed to do so far:

Untyped mediator code

```
let commands = {};
    export const registerCommand = ({ type, handler }) => {
      commands[type] = handler;
    };

    export const dispatchCommand= async ({ type, command }) => {
      logTime(type);
      return commands[type](command);
    };
```

I'd register the command like this:

```
registerCommand("CREATE_NEW_INSTITUTION_ACCOUNT", CreateNewInstitutionAccountCommandHandler);
```

And I'd fire it, like this:

```
const result = await dispatchCommand("CREATE_NEW_INSTITUTION_ACCOUNT", { 
  tenantId: 'my-id',
  employeeId: 'the-other-id'
});
```

I've been trying for several hours on how to create a shared type, so I can safely register the command with an already available type.

Note: I could always do 2 types, but that would somewhat defeat the purpose of the type system as I keep forgetting to add it in several places

Here's the approach so far (TypeScript):

```
type MediatorDispatcherForCommands = (({
  type,
  handler,
  command,
}: {
  type: "SAVE_EVIDENCE_EVALUATION";
  handler?: typeof SaveEvidenceEvaluationCommandHandler;
  command?: SaveEvidenceEvaluationCommand;
}) => ReturnType<typeof SaveEvidenceEvaluationCommandHandler>) &
  (({
    type,
    handler,
    command,
  }: {
    type: "SEED_DATABASE_INDIVIDUAL";
    handler?: typeof SaveEvidenceEvaluationCommandHandler;
    command?: SeedDataForIndividualAccountCommand;
  }) => ReturnType<typeof SeedDataForIndividualAccountCommandHandler>);
```

I've tried a myriad of approaches. I've tried separating it into different objects. I've tried forcefully required a single parameter (Which I don't know how when it's destructured in the parameter... by destructuring it allows me to autocomplete when a `type` key is provided).

This works for the dispatcher but not for the command.

```
   export const dispatchCommand: MediatorDispatcherForCommands = async ({ type, command }) => {
      logTime(type);
      return commands[type](command);
    };
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I ended giving up for a universal solution... This was the closest I could get it:

I'd do a union operation in the argument parameter. This would allow me to autocomplete when needed.

Later on, in the dispatcher, I'd create a return type, that I'd explicitly pass it.

See down below:

This allows me to autocomplete it both in the dispatcher and the registrar.

```
export type MediatorCommands =
  | {
      type: "CREATE_ROLE";
      arg: CreatePermissionCommand | typeof createPermissionCommandHandler;
    }
  | {
      type: "CREATE_NEW_INSTITUTION_ACCOUNT";
      arg:
        | CreateNewInstitutionAccountCommand
        | typeof CreateNewInstitutionAccountCommandHandler;
    }
```

Then my functions:

```
// This is hacky... but it works!
let commands: {
  [x: string]: Function;
} = {};

export function registerCommand({ type, arg }: MediatorCommands) {
  commands[type] = arg as Function;
}

export async function dispatchCommand<TResult>({
  type,
  arg,
}: MediatorCommands) {
  logTime(type);
  return commands[type](arg) as Promise<TResult>;
}
```

Then, to register a command:

```
registerCommand({
  type: "CREATE_ROLE",
  arg: createPermissionCommandHandler,
});
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
await dispatch<CreatedRoleRT>({
          type: "CREATE_ROLE",
          arg: {
            tenantId,
            employeeId,
          },
        });
```

The `CreatedRoleRT` type comes from another singular file (to reduce dependencies), which holds all the references of the return types of the handler.

```
type CreatedRoleRT = ReturnType<typeof createPermissionCommandHandler>;
```

This isn't perfect... but it works !